What is Helix Nebula made up of?
The Helix is a planetary nebula, the glowing gaseous envelope expelled by a dying, sun-like star. Helix nebula consists of two gaseous disks, how they are formed or which material is present in it.

Probably start with Helix Nebula at Wikipedia, but more generally the makeup of a nebula follows the makeup of the star that cast off the material. Those Wikipedia articles don't appear to directly address the Helix Nebula makeup. Maybe searching for "helix nebula spectral analysis" would help.

@GregBurghardt thanks for your help.
